# The key combination Alt + 6 for copy in nano does not work in GNOME terminal emulator Tilix

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, nano, tilix

The key combination `Alt + 6` for copy in `nano` does not work in `tilix`

**Does anyone know how to fix this?** I had a look through all the key commands, but did not find any entry for `Alt + 6` being already in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tilix version: `1.9.6` you can manually change and set key commands. Disable <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> which is set to switch to terminal Nr.6. by default.

[image]